# How to convert javascript to UML?

Tags: javascript, uml, class-diagram

I'm learning javascript and i come from a java/c++ background, and i was wondering if exists a way to transform javascript (with or without ES2015 classes) code into UML class diagram, or if we can transform javascript code into java so then i can get UML class diagram, with visual paradigm for example. I know that probably is not useful, but i'm still learning this language

Comment: I don't think that it is very usefull to do that if you want to learn JavaScript since JS is not soley object oriented. But maybe [this](https://dukescript.com/update/2016/07/01/transcript-to-java.html) sets you on a track to transcribe the JS code to Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion is to try [jsUML](http://jsuml.sourceforge.net/)

**What is JS/UML?**

JS/UML is a plugin for the Eclipse IDE that creates UML models and diagrams from JavaScript code.

**What does JS/UML do?**

Imports JavaScript that is written in the styles of JSDoc, jGrouseDoc or YUI

Creates a UML model of the parsed JavaScript code which can be viewed using the Eclipse UML2 model editor

Creates UML diagrams that can be editing using the diagram editors from Eclipse's Papyrus project

Generates documentation for the modeled API using provided templates or custom templates you design

**What is next at JS/UML?**

Stub Generation - New templates to create javascript stubs from existing UML diagrams

Services Generation - New templates to create services based on those from zoe-express